# Altium Designer: Is there anything similar to trim in AutoCAD? Is there a better alternative method to remove stubs?

Tags: altium, trace

Let's say I have the track/trace below.

I want to remove the track stub so it ends at the via.

I could click on the end vertex of the track and drag the stub into the via until its gone, but with much long tracks, or tracks made of multiple segments, this isn't possible.

Is there anything similar to 'trim' in AutoCAD, where by simply clicking, a track will delete any extension until the next node (intersection, via etc.)

Failing such a feature, what is the fastest workflow for achieving the same?

[image: track to trim]

Answer (score 1):

I usually slice the track at the end where I want to trim the track then select a piece of the remainig tracks I want deleted, press [tab] and all the connected copper will be selected.  Then press delete to delete the selected tracks.  Play around with it, it's handy but if your traces run into copper pour etc. pressing tab will select them too.  I sometimes will select a trace, press tab to select all connected copper and press [ctrl][alt]-g and have Altium gloss the traces.  You can always undo if it's not what you like.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite method is simply selecting the stub farthest from the connected line and pressing backspace. It will delete the segment and auto-select the next segment of the line, so you can clean up quite a bit of track with just a few key-presses.

Comment: This works if the line is made of multiple segments. But I need an approach that we create sub-segments from tracks where they intersect stuff (vias, junctions...)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the closest you will get to emulating that "trim" command is with the keyboard shortcuts : SS - for Select Single Layer Connection, or SC - for Select Connection ... once the portion is selected you can delete only the part required for deletion.

The workflow generally involves selecting the track(s) or object(s) using the SS, SC or SN selection commands and then deleting (if they are not locked - may require unlocking first to complete deletion)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I'm trying this, but both SS and SC seem to select the entire verticle blue track in my image example above. It doesn't create a sub-divided track at the via.

Comment: It requires just one additional step. First select the track that connects to the via on the side that you want deleted, then delete that portion. Second, use SC on the remainder of the blue track you want deleted. This should select only the remainder as it is no longer part of the via net. Then, delete the remainder of the blue track. As mentioned, there is no direct equivalent in Altium, it's a slight work around and it works with any other object in a similar scenario (via, or pad etc). good luck

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow this Altium documentation: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-cmd-runscissorsrunscissors-ad?version=22

The slicing track part of this link is what you are looking for. This command is accessed from both PCB and PCB Library Editors by choosing the Edit » Slice Tracks command from the main menus.

By the way, here is also a step by step PCB designing guideline for altium. You can take a look:

https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Altium_Designer_Step_by_Step_Guide_on_PCB_Board_Design_890f88b1.html